# vaadin grid hide column

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer, vaadin, vaadin-grid

Hello I am new to this polymer framework. I have a drop-down list with paper checkbox elements for hiding some columns in a vaadin grid. Here is my sample code

```
<paper-icon-button icon="icons:menu" slot="dropdown-trigger" alt="hide-menu"></paper-icon-button>
    <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{toggleColumns}}" as="column" index-as="index">
            <paper-icon-item>
                <paper-checkbox checked="{{column.hidden}}" on-click="_makeHidden">[[column.prop]]</paper-checkbox>
            </paper-icon-item>
        </template>
    </paper-listbox>
</paper-menu-button>
```

My vaadin-grid is given below

```
<vaadin-grid id="material" class='content' aria-label="Basic Binding Example" page-size="10" column-reordering-allowed>
    <vaadin-grid-selection-column widthtrue="66px" flex="0" select-all="{{selectAll}}">
        <template class="header">
            <paper-checkbox checked="{{selectAll}}"></paper-checkbox>
        </template>
        <template>
            <paper-checkbox checked="{{selected}}"></paper-checkbox>
        </template>
    </vaadin-grid-selection-column>
    <vaadin-grid-column id="firstName" resizable>
        <template class="header">
            <vaadin-grid-sorter path="firstName">                            
                 <div class="cell">
                     <span>First Name</span><iron-icon icon="icons:arrow-upward"></iron-icon>
                 </div>
            </vaadin-grid-sorter>
        </template>
                    <template>[[item.firstName]]</template>
                </vaadin-grid-column>
                <vaadin-grid-column id="lastName" resizable>
                    <template class="header">Last Name</template>
                    <template>[[item.lastName]]</template>
                </vaadin-grid-column>
                <vaadin-grid-column id="address" width="150px" resizable>
                    <template class="header">Address</template>
                    <template>
                        <p style="white-space: normal">[[item.address.street]], [[item.address.city]]</p>
                    </template>
                </vaadin-grid-column>
            </vaadin-grid>
```

My toggleColumn array is

```
toggleColumns: {
                type: Array,
                notify: true,
                value: [
                    {
                        id: 0, prop: 'FirstName', hidden: false
                    }, {
                        id: 1, prop: 'LastName', hidden: false
                    }, {
                        id: 2, prop: 'Address', hidden: false
                    }
                ]
            }
```

On clicking the checkbox the "column.prop" is changed accordingly. But I cant figure out how to set that to grid column hidden property. For example clicking the first checkbox makes `toggleColumns[0].hidden` to true. Now how to make `this.$.firstName.hidden` to be true?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `toggleColumns` is an array, you can use [Polymer's syntax to bind to array items](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#array-binding). For example, this syntax binds to the second element in an array, named `stringArray`:

```
<div>{{stringArray.1}}</div>
```

In your case, to bind the first element's `hidden` property to `<vaadin-grid-column>.hidden`, your code would look like this:

```
<vaadin-grid-column hidden="[[toggleColumns.0.hidden]]">
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/eeWzep?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

Mind your [splices](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/model-data#notifysplices) when mutating arrays.

In your checkbox handlers, make sure to use your component's (inherited) array mutation methods:

```
const colObj = this.toggleColumns[colPos];
colObj.hidden = !wasChecked;
this.splice('toggleColumns', colPos, 1, colObj);
```

Only then the binding @tony19 described will update correctly.